# How to solve "Compile Error : type mismatch" error in VB6?

Tags: vb6

It seems that there are already some answers available but I can't find proper answer for my question.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Combo2_click()
Dim item_id, price As Integer
Dim item_name As String
If Combo2.Index Is 0 Then
    price = 30
ElseIf Combo2.Index Is 1 Then
    price = 40
ElseIf Combo2.Index Is 2 Then
    price = 50
ElseIf Combo2.Index Is 3 Then
    price = 60
Else
    price = 55
End If
End Sub
```

I am getting error as "Compile Error : Type MisMatch" ... I don't know why! It is showing error on the like `Private Sub COmbo2_click()` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code:

1- You should use `Combo2.ListIndex` instead of `.Index`. (because `index` is used for something else and that's when your control is an element in an array)

2- You should replace `Is` with `=` (and that's what throws the exception of `Type mismatch`).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Additional info for point 2  "Is" is used in "Select Case" not If.  That was so cryptic :)

Comment: @Jules the operator `Is` isn't restricted to use in `Select Case` only, it's used to compare between two objects, and yes it can be used in If statement (when comparing a pair of objects).

Comment: Yes you are right. I was going to add you can use is to compare object with nothing, but my comment was cryptic enough.

Comment: Another note - `Dim a, b As Integer` declares a as variant.